# Verification of an integral reduction for $I_n=\int_{0}^{2}(2x-x^2)^n\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, solution-verification, reduction-formula

> Find the reduction formula for the integral $$I_n=\int_{0}^{2}(2x-x^2)^n\,dx.$$

I wanted to verify my formula for this integral. Please check for mistakes.

***My Solution:***

Since $2x-x^2$ is symmetric about $x=1$ in interval $[0,2]$, we can write the integral as $$I_n=2\int_{0}^{1}x^n(2-x)^n\, dx.$$

Using $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=\int_{a}^{b}f(a+b-x)\,dx$, we get:

$$I_n=2\int_{0}^{1}(1-x)^n(1+x)^ndx=2\int_{0}^{1}(1-x^2)^{n}\,dx.$$

Let
\begin{align*}
x&=\sin\theta\\
dx&=\cos\theta\, d\theta.
\end{align*}

Thus $$I_n=2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^{2n+1}\theta\, d\theta.$$

Now we know that $$2k\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^k\theta\,d\theta=2(k-1)\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^{k-2}\theta\, d\theta.$$

Putting $k=2n+1$, we get:

$$(2n+1)I_n=2nI_{n-1}\implies I_n=\dfrac{2nI_{n-1}}{2n+1}.$$

Please check this solution for any mistakes. Also please help in finding $\lim_{n\to \infty}I_n.$

***Thank you***

Comment: I fixed a few typos that didn't affect your results: $I_n=2\int_{0}^{2}(1-x)^n(1+x)^ndx=2\int_{0}^{1}(1-x^2)\,dx$ should be $I_n=2\int_{0}^{1}(1-x)^n(1+x)^ndx=2\int_{0}^{1}(1-x^2)^{n}\,dx.$

Comment: But also yes, otherwise your solution looks good!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the $\lim_{n\to\infty}I_{n}$, we can use the [Dominated Convergence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem).

In this case, it suffices to check that

1. The sequence of functions $\{f_n\}$ given by $f_{n}(x) = (2x-x^2)^n$ converges pointwise to some function $f$ on the interval $[0,2]$.
2. There exists some integrable function $g$ such that for all $x \in [0,2]$ and for all $n$ we have $|f_n(x)| \le g(x)$.

If both conditions are met we can conclude that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}I_{n} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^2 f_n(x)\,dx = \int_0^2\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)\,dx = \int_0^2 f(x)\,dx.$$

Considering the pointwise limit, we have that for $x\in [0,2]$,
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}(2x- x^2)^n &= \begin{cases} 1, &x = 1\\
0, &\text{else}
\end{cases}\\
&= 0\quad \text{a.e.}
\end{align*}
which means the first condition is satisfied. Furthermore, for $x\in [0,2]$, $|(2x-x^2)^{n}| \leq 1,$ meaning the second condition is also satisfied.  Therefore, we have that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}I_{n} = \int_{0}^{2} 0\,dx = 0.$$

Comment: I'm not quite sure if we can transfer the limit inside the integral, and if we can, then what are the criteria for doing so (bit weak at theory)? Thanks for help

Comment: We can, and the reason is the [Dominated Convergence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem).  I will edit my answer to include a statement of the theorem.